# CORRUPT_MESSAGE when trying to run a Kafka JDBC source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to run a Kafka JDBC source connector with the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "source-mariadb-VIEW_GIORGOS", 
    "config": { "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", 
                "tasks.max":"10", 
                "connection.url":"jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/kafka?user=myuser&password=mypass", 
                "table.whitelist":"VIEW_GIORGOS", 
                "mode":"timestamp", 
                "timestamp.column.name":"ROWVERSION", 
                "validate.non.null":"false", 
                "topic.prefix":"GIORGOS-", 
                "table.types":"TABLE,VIEW", 
                "poll.interval.ms":"1000",
                "consumer.group.id":"mytopicgroup1" 
    }
}
```

But Kafka Connect reports the following error:

```
WARN [Producer clientId=producer-8] Got error produce response with correlation id 1504 on topic-partition GIORGOS-VW_GIORGOS, retrying (2147483149 attempts left). 
Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:526)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that this error was related to the retention policy.

`compact` policy requires a key and a value. Since a view does not have a key, the message is corrupted. Changing policy to `delete` has fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! That really works. Little notice: do not forget to delete and recreate the topic explicitly.